# JMeter: run a single Thread Group with dynamically generated Number of Threads (users)

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I have several Thread Groups in a test plan, that are exactly the same with the exception of the Number of Threads, which keeps incrementing from TG to TG. Whenever I have to change a single thing, it's a nightmare to have to go to each and every one of them to make the same change.

Is there a way to make one single Thread Group run several times with a different Number of Threads that is generated dynamically, and have each Sample inside it be on a single row of a Summary Report listener (for example)?

Thanks.

Comment: Any feedback ? If answer is ok you should accept it so that it's helpful to otherd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all samplers inside a TransactionController or SimpleController in the first Thread Group then use a ModuleController in all other thread Groups referencing the first one.

Comment: It works, but I wish I could just feed the Number of Threads from a csv file, user defined variables, or even some function - in order to avoid having to actually create all the Thread Groups and manually change their Numbers. But your solution is close enough, thanks!